# Does _start call my program's main function and other essential setup functions?

Tags: linux, c, gcc, linker

I'm reading a textbook which describes how loader works:

> When the loader runs,  it copies chunks of the executable object file into the code and data segments. Next, the loader jumps to the program’s entry point, which is always the address of the `_start` function.The _start function calls the system startup function, `__libc_start_main`

From the answer of [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62709030/what-is-libc-start-main-and-start), we have the below pseudo-code about the execution flow:

```
_start:
   call __setup_for_c       ; set up C environment
   call __libc_start_main   ; set up standard library
   call _main               ; call your main
   call __libc_stop_main    ; tear down standard library
   call __teardown_for_c    ; tear down C environment
   jmp  __exit              ; return to OS
```

My questions are:

1. I used `objdump` to check the assembly code of the program and I found `_start` only call `__libc_start_main` as picture below shows:

   [image]

   What about the rest of functions like `call __setup_for_c`, `_main` , etc.? Especially my program's main function, I can't see how it get called. So is the pseudo-code about the execution flow correct?
2. What does `__libc_start_main` setup standard library mean? Why does the standard library need to be setup? Doesn't that standard library just need to be linked by the dynamic linker when the program is loaded?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63806608/12231187). Also, the question falls much more under the scope of StackOverflow than U&L StackExchange as it is a programming question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The other function calls described in the linked answer give a synopsis of what needs to happen; the actual implementation details in the GNU C library are different, either using “constructors” (`_dl_start_user`), or explicitly in `__libc_start_main`. `__libc_start_main` also takes care of calling the user’s `main`, which is why you don’t see it *called* in your disassembly — but its address is passed along (see the `lea` just the `callq`). `__libc_start_main` also takes care of the program exit, and never returns; that’s the reason for the `hlt` just after the `callq`, which will crash the program if the function returns.
2. The library needs quite a lot of setup nowadays:

   - some of its own relocation
   - thread-local storage setup
   - pthread setup
   - destructor registration
   - vDSO setup (on Linux)
   - ctype initialisation
   - copying the program name, arguments and environment to various library variables

   etc. See the x86-64-specific [`sysdeps/x86_64/start.S`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/x86_64/start.S) and the generic [`csu/libc-start.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/libc-start.c), [`csu/init-first.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/init-first.c), and [`misc/init-misc.c`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=csu/init-misc.c) among others.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if `__libc_start_main` never return then why `hlt` is needed after `callq`? isn't that `callq` can be the last instruction of `_start`?

Comment: It’s a fail-safe — if for some reason the function returns, execution won’t continue.

Comment: @amjad `hlt` will generate a general-protection fault if called from unprivileged code -- thence the comment in the source code "hlt /\* Crash if somehow \`exit' does return.  \*/"